# Can "modern" Yarn add a dependency without a manifest?

Tags: yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

In "classic" Yarn, you could add a dependency that did not have a package.json due to this pull: [#3624](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/pull/3624).

Can "modern" Yarn (i.e. Yarn 2/3) do the same? I have failed to find any documentation about this. When I try I get an error:

`yarn add bayes.js@rasmusab/bayes.js`

Leads to:

`YN0001: │ Error: bayes.js@https://github.com/rasmusab/bayes.js.git#commit=62204b7cb8dba369b9ece99bdd7e99ad527224aa: Manifest not found`

I'm not sure if this is because "modern" Yarn doesn't support this, or if I am doing it wrong.

Comment: I faced the same issue, I had to move back to yarn v1 after hitting this blocker.

Comment: I worked around it by forking the repo and adding a minimal package.json, but this is less than an ideal solution.